# CommonDomain/EventStore Interface Fetching

Tags: cqrs, neventstore, commondomain

I'd like to access my aggregate root by an interface it implements:

```
 repository.GetById[[IMyInterface]](id);
```

What do I need to tell CommonDomain or EventStore to accomplish this? I believe my IConstructAggregates receives the *Implementation* Type of the aggregate that stored the events. Do i need to just keep my own map of ids.

For example, say I have these agg roots :

```
class AggRoot1 : IInterface1, IInterface2 {}
class AggRoot2 : IInterface1, IInterface2 {}
```

I already saved an aggregate1 instance having 'idFromAggRoot1'.
Now I want to fetch like so:

```
repository.GetById<IInterface1>(idFromAggRoot1);
```

How can I know what I should create later since there are two implementors of IInterface1? AggRoot1? AggRoot2? IInterface1? Activator would bomb here so I know I need to implement IConstructAggregates but wonder if there is some other descriptor to tell me what the original commit agg root type was.

Comment: Please explain to me what the pratical use of such a construct is? Are you thinking in terms of "roles"?

Comment: Just saw this - The practical use is coding to interface on my Aggregate Roots without requiring client knowledge of the actual implementation it is executing against.

Comment: I acknowledge that decoupling might be a good thing, but can you give an example of two aggregate root types that would implement the same interface but not share the same implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IConstructAggregates.Build()` method can be implemented to return whatever type you need.

In `Common.AggregateFactory` the default implementation creates an instance of the Aggregate via `Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IAggregate`.

An own implementation might look like this:

```
public class MyAggregateFactory : IConstructAggregates
{
    public IAggregate Build(Type type, Guid id, IMemento snapshot)
    {
        if (type == typeof(IMyInterface))
            return new MyAggregate();
        else
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IAggregate;
    }
}
```

Edit: The aggregate type is being stored in the event message's header as `EventMessage.Header[EventStoreRepository.AggregateTypeHeader]`

Comment: Thank you but still doesn't answer my question. I have edited my post to provide more details

Comment: That helps, thank you. It looks like I'll need to extend the EventStoreRepository to fetch the stream and read the first event to get that metadata. I have put an issue on the repo to provide this in the IConstructAggregates.